Motivation behind supersymmetric algebra
In SUSY we introduce two new fermionic operators $Q_\alpha$ and $\bar{Q}_\dot{\alpha}$, and postulate the anticommuting relation
$$
\{Q_\alpha,\bar{Q}_\dot{\alpha}\} = 2\sigma_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}^\mu P_\mu,
$$
from which we can derive the rest of the (anti)commutation rules for the super-Poincaré algebra. My question is, what is the intuition behind introducing such an anticommutation relation? Why does $P$ appear in it?

There was no physical motivation, when such algebras were introduced in the 1970s. They emerged in the theoretical backdrop of conjectural string theories involving fermions and bosons, as a "what if" question connecting particles differing by spin 1/2, generalizing such connections by spin 1 differences effected by the Poincare group.

P appears as the algebra needs to be covariant under the action of the Lorentz group.

Thank you so much Prof. Zachos!!
